# How to build a model's custom RESTAdapter depending on route?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm very new to Ember.js, so still getting the fundamentals down. I have a model, let's call it `dog`, whose data is coming from an external API. The API only allows you to get big dogs and small dogs separately:

```
http://api.example.com/big/dogs
http://api.example.com/small/dogs
```

If I were to have `big` and `small` routes of my own—each of which would get the appropriate list of dogs—how could I customize my `DogAdapter`'s `buildURL` method to put together the correct API call depending on the current route?

This is a very simplified example, please let me know if anything needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. As an example, my `big` route should return:

```
this.store.query( 'dog', { size: 'big' } )
```

and my `DogAdapter` should define something like:

```
buildUrl( model, id, snapshot, req, query ) {
    return 'http://api.example.com/' + query.size + '/dogs'
}
```

Comment: Your solution might bite you in the future. First, this.store.findQuery and this.store.findAll returns different arrays (second will be auto updated array, first - not). Second, you need to parse request type, to check query params and so on, and and will lead to not maintainable code. I suggest you to use different models as you have different routes for them. You can always use inheritance and mixins for models. From my side, it's easier to maintain and to understand.

Comment: @Microfed Thanks for the suggestion. I get that approach, but doesn't it seem wrong making separate models to represent subsets of a single model, just to conform to someone else's API? I'm sure I might be missing something fundamental here.

Comment: It depends on interpretation, of course. Ember-data expects rest-like APIs by default, and you need to do something, if your API doesn't meet the requirements. If you want that 'models' to work like a similar objects (for ex., filtering and sorting them in one list), then your approach is closer. Otherwise, if models are really different and you might need to distinguish one from another, it's better to have different classes at the beginning. :)

Comment: I was having same issue and asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702385/ember-cli-custom-routing-for-very-basic-dropdown . you are using consider your DOG as a resource and big/small are attributes so it should be `api.sample.com/dog?size=big`